# Infinite loop when trying to create streams

Tags: java, networking, server

So I'm building a small chat application but I am having some troubling setting up my server. The code below is my constructor in my server thread:

```
public ServerThread() {
    System.out.println("Before");

    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3500);
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("After");
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    connected = true;
}
```

As you can see I have 2 prints, "Before" and "After. Between these two, something happends that causes the program to enter an infinite loop. `socket = serverSocket.accept();` I can't catch the exception either. Not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Do you even know what `accept()` do ?

Comment: Hint: try connecting to your running server on 3500, and see that the "infinite loop" is not so infinite after all.

Comment: A server socket **WAITS** for requests to come in over the network.

your `serverSocket.accept();` will wait till connection is made

Comment: Try to run the .accept() methode from an another Thread. Because it is blocking the JAT.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment yet) but accept() will block until a connection is made. It's not an infinite loop either, it's just that the method will block until something connects to that socket.

Are you sure your client connects ok?